# как переписать удаленную ветку master?

Tags: git, git-merge

Такая ситуация я работаю один с iOS в Xcode (может это имеет значение)

И делаю комиты в процессе работы и вдруг вижу, что удаленная ветка отделилась почему то (наверное я что то сделал не так, но все равно странное поведение ветки при условии, что я один в этом репозитории).

Выглядит это сейчас вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда пишу `git push` то в output говориться, что нужно сделать `git pull` сначала(как так получилось, что мне нужно делать git pull не понятно, работаю в одной ветке один...).

Ок, делаю `git pull` получаю конфликт в файле `Main.storyboar`, такие конфликты очень тяжело исправить(по крайней мере для меня новичка в iOS), у меня даже не получается открыть этот файл.

Выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот теперь вопрос в том, можно как то переписать `remote master` ветку?

У меня есть нормальная ветка `local master` и я просто хочу залить ее в удаленный репозиторий сверху того `master` который сейчас там и не делать никаких merge и pull, просто сверху ее записать как основную

Можно так?)

---

Вот, что получается если выполнить команду `git push --force master` из ответа @KoVadim

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git push --force master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

С такой командой  `git push --force origin master` получаю вот такой вывод

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git push --force origin master
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 11.10 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 39 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected   branch on this project.
To https://gitlab.com/alekseytimoshchenko/FitzzIOS.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to   'https://gitlab.com/alekseytimoshchenko/FitzzIOS.git'
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$
```

**правка**

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git fetch
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git checkout  master 
Already on 'master'
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 7 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git merge
Auto-merging Fitzz/Main.storyboard
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Fitzz/Main.storyboard
Auto-merging Fitzz/Info.plist
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Fitzz/Info.plist
Auto-merging Fitzz/CameraViewController.swift
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Fitzz/CameraViewController.swift
Auto-merging Fitzz.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Fitzz.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git checkout --ours -- Fitzz.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git checkout --ours --   Fitzz/CameraViewController.swift
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git checkout --ours -- Fitzz/Info.plist
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git checkout --ours --  Fitzz/Main.storyboard
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Fitzz admin$ git status 
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 7 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
You have unmerged paths.
(fix conflicts and run "git commit")
(use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

both modified:   Fitzz.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
both added:      Fitzz/CameraViewController.swift
both modified:   Fitzz/Info.plist
both modified:   Fitzz/Main.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом, Вам нужен форсированный пуш. `git push --force origin master`. Но это очень опасная команда и она перетирает текущую ветку на удаленном репозитории. Если Вы работаете самостоятельно - скорее ничего плохого не будет. Но если работаете в команде - нужно десять раз подумать и все равно не  делать.

Судя по картинке - там сейчас в процессе мердж (но я не уверен - гуевым утилитам доверия ноль). Но если будет ругаться, что сейчас мердж - его можно отменить `git merge --abort`.

Если подобная стратегия не работает, можно попробовать все таки сделать "правильно".

вначале подтянем удаленные изменения (ну мало чего)

```
git fetch
```

переключимся в мастер

```
git checkout master
```

смерджим ручками

```
git merge
```

тут у нас будут конфликты. Их нужно решить. Для начала делаем

```
git status
```

и смотрим на конфликтные файлы. Так как хочется забыть о удаленном мастере, будем мержить "в нашу сторону". Для каждого конфликтного файла делаем такое

```
git checkout --ours -- <имяфайла>
```

этой командой мы говорим гиту, что хотим решить конфликт, сказав, что наша версия файла правильная.

и не забываем сказать гиту, что мы решили конфликт

```
git add <имяфайла>
```

и снова смотрим `git status` - там не должно быть файлов с "both modified". Теперь нужно в среде разработки скомпилировать и проверить, что все работает. Если все устраивает - коммитим и пушим

```
git commit -m "merge master"
git push
```

Comment: Но в моей ситуации это то что нужно я так понимаю? Я попробовал эту команду но не получилось, добавил в вопрос

Comment: там потерялось слово.

Comment: все равно не получилось( Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Похоже у Вас на гитлабе сделана "защита от дурака" (и это хорошо). Как перенастроить гитлаб - я не скажу.

Comment: хмм... ок, может еще есть идея как поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: Ну идею я понял, получить изменения, сказать что локальные верные, добавить и закомитить, но все равно у меня показывает `both modified` , такое впечатление как будто  я не правильно использую эту команду `git checkout --ours -- <имяфайла>` . Добавил в вопрос лог, что сделал не так?

Comment: все правильно. После того, как сделали checkout для нужных файлов, нужно их добавить - git add имя_файла. И потом коммитит, по старинке.

Comment: Оо круто) Точно) записал себе все команды на будущее, очень полезно. Но я вот подумал чем такой подход отличается от push --force ? Ведь результат такой же...

Comment: Если работаете только Вы и только на одной машине - никаких проблем. Но если есть ещё один разработичик, который ведет свой код (то есть, у него есть также мастер, в который он закоммитил, но не пушил), то после форсированного пуша от Вас, у него будут проблемы - ему нужно будет аккуратно спулить, смерджить, понять, почему был откат, что бы не запушить левого. И да, этим вторым разработчиком можете быть Вы сами, просто на другой машине.